# I need the formula to check for a word in a range and then return that word to a specific cell

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I am using the following formula but keep getting the `#SPILL!` error:

```
=IF(Table7[@[Day 1]:[Day 25]]="leaver";"Leaver";"n/a")
```

Comment: does it work with Comma, instead of ; ?

Comment: You'll need to at least mention *what technology you're talking about!* Better: add appropriate tags.

Comment: I am using basic excel to create a attendance register. I need the formula to lookup each day and if the word "leave" appears on any day in the range/row then a specific cell should update with the work leaver

Comment: `#SPILL!` means your formula working fine but couldn't spill results to cells. You must clear all cells to spill results by dynamic array formulas. In case of table use `@` implicit intersection operator at the beginning of formula to return only first result of each row/cell.

Comment: Read this two article from Microsoft. [1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/implicit-intersection-operator-ce3be07b-0101-4450-a24e-c1c999be2b34#:~:text=What%20is%20implicit%20intersection%3F,only%20contain%20a%20single%20value.), [2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-to-correct-a-spill-error-ffe0f555-b479-4a17-a6e2-ef9cc9ad4023)

Comment: I need "Leaver" to appear only once in the cell I added the formula too. is there an alternative formula that does the same thing. I'm a little lost here.

Comment: Thanks Harun24hr , I'll go through it

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MATCH` formula to find if your range contains word "Leaver".
Example:

```
=IF(MATCH("leaver",Table1[@[Column1]:[Column4]],0)>0,"Leaver","N/A")
```

Output:
[image]

If it finds one ore more instance of "leaver" in given range it puts "Leaver" in `E2`, otherwise "N/A"